# How to sign your kernel and bootloader?

Tags: grub2, lubuntu, signature

## How to sign your kernel and bootloader?

How do I sign my kernel and bootloader?

**Update (04-Feb-2021)**
Don't think I made clear what it is that I'm trying to do. I want to do away with OEM keys and only use my own keys. I'm trying to run **Secure Boot** with **Full Disk Encryption**, including **Boot**.

### Preparation

1. Disable **Secure Boot** and **Delete existing keys**.
2. Download and install the [mikos/cryptboot](https://github.com/xmikos/cryptboot) tool.
3. Install package dependencies (listed in the readme)

### Cryptboot configuration

Made some changes to the config file (these are the changes I made to reflect my setup).

```bsh
# Encrypted boot device name (/dev/mapper/$BOOT_CRYPT_NAME)
# (have to be specified in /etc/crypttab)
BOOT_CRYPT_NAME="LUKS_BOOT"

# Boot entry in UEFI Boot Manager (if using GRUB boot loader)
EFI_ID_GRUB="ubuntu"

# Path to GRUB boot loader EFI file (relative to EFI System partition)
EFI_PATH_GRUB="EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi"
```

### Steps taken

```bsh
# Create and enroll keys (must be in setup mode, verify with bootctl)
cryptboot-efikeys create
cryptboot-efikeys enroll

# Sign kernel
cryptboot-efikeys sign /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-65-generic

# Sign bootloader
cryptboot update-grub
```

When I reboot and enable **Secure Boot** I will get this error:

```
error: Secure Boot forbids loading module from (cryptouuid/abcdef0123456789)/grub/x86_64-efi/normal.mod
```

And when I fix that by bundling/pre-loading (with `--modules` parameter on `grub-install`) the modules I get this error:

```
error: /vmlinuz-5.4.0-65-generic has invalid signature.
error: you need to load the kernel first

Press any key to continue...
```

When I verify the signatures, I get an output saying it has multiple signatures but that they're okay:

1. Canonicals signature
2. My custom signature

So I thought that maybe removing the Canonical signature would help. Found a program called `pesign` which would let me remove signatures from binaries. I removed the Canonical signature, then verfied that the signature is still okay by running:

```bsh
cryptboot-efikeys verify /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-65-generic
```

All seems to be good, it says the signature is valid (OK). When I reboot I still get the same error as before. Do not think that was the issue (having Canonicals signature on it).

### Additional information

I have double checked that my keys are enrolled properly.

```bsh
cryptboot-efikeys list
# All UEFI Secure Boot keys enrolled in your UEFI firmware:
# Variable PK, length 835
# PK: List 0, type X509
#   ...
# Variable KEK, length 837
# KEK: List 0, type X509
#   ...
# Variable db, length 835
# db: List 0, type X509
#   ...
# Variable dbx, length -4
# Variable MokList has no entries
```

The double check

```bsh
moktuil --import /boot/efikeys/PK.cer
# SKIP: efikeys/PK.cer is already in PK
mokutil --import /boot/efikeys/KEK.cer
# SKIP: efikeys/KEK.cer is already in KEK
mokutil --import /boot/efikeys/db.cer
# SKIP: efikeys/db.cer is already in db
```

When I run `mokutil --list-enrolled` it tells me that the MOK list is empty.

```bsh
mokutil --list-enrolled
# MokListRT is empty
```

When looking at various guides and articles they all say that when importing your keys with `mokutil` you will be prompted for a password, then have to reboot and select the desired key. Then after the reboot verify that the key(s) were enrolled properly.

Since my output of `mokutil --list-enrolled` says the list is empty I get the feeling that this is what is causing the error I'm seeing. I've read through the `cryptboot-efikeys` script and it is not using `mokutil` anywhere, maybe that helps.

My keys are already enrolled and `mokutil` won't take them so if this is causing problems I do not know how to fix it without ditching `cryptboot` and doing all operations myself, which I prefer not having to.

Also tried the `grub-efi-amd64-signed` package which will give you the option to use the `--uefi-secure-boot` option on `grub-install` but this did not seem to make any difference.

### System and environment information

- Ubuntu `20.04`
- GRUB `2.04`
- Kernel `5.4.0-65`

## Update (04-Feb-2021)

I've done away with the `cryptboot` tool and started doing all steps manually. The issue of `mokutil` not taking my keys remains, however if I first load my keys in MOK and later into UEFI it all works fine.

I have since found out that removing `grub-efi-amd64-signed` makes it so that you lose the `shimx64.efi` and `mmx64.efi`, that was probably the reason I was unable to launch MokManager and the reason secure boot wasn't working.

Instead of having `grub-efi-amd64-signed` installed, I tried running `grub-install` while having `shim` and `grub-efi-amd64` installed. Did not give me `shimx64.efi` therefor not being able to start MokManager. I could overcome this by copying `/usr/lib/shim/shimx64.efi` to `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/` and then adding it as a boot entry with `efibootmgr`. This would let me run MokManger on reboot but would still add the default keys (more on default keys in a bit).

Did a step back and reinstalled my system without any encryption, just to see what vanilla Ubuntu 20.04 would do in terms of setting up. I'm able to set up Secure Boot on the vanilla Ubuntu 20.04 desktop installation, solely using my own keys (kinda).

When adding my key using `mokutil --import key.der` I'm also getting the Microsoft shim signing key and the Canonical secure boot signing key. This is something I don't think I want but cannot be sure yet as I do not fully understand where the MOK keys come in to play. Deleting the Microsoft and Canonical keys from MOK using `mokutil` is not possible. I'm now looking in to compiling shim from source, hoping the default keys are not enrolled.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create signature keys for PK, KEK, DB and DBX.
   You can use openssl for this.
   Save x509 Certificate (for PK) into machine also load *.[esl](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/cert-to-efi-sig-list.1.html) (KEK.esl, DB.esl and DBX.esl) to device.
2. Use [sbsign](https://man.archlinux.org/man/extra/sbsigntools/sbsign.1) to sign *.efi files. With [sbverify](https://man.archlinux.org/man/extra/sbsigntools/sbverify.1.en) you can check this
3. If you start from grub2 directly (without shim), **you have to sign ALL files loading by grub with OpenPGP**!

   For example:

   - grub.cfg -> grub.cfg.sig
   - *.mod -> *.mod.sig
   - vmlinuz-5.4.0-65-generic -> vmlinuz-5.4.0-65-generic.sig
   - ...

   Embedded the public part of OpenPGP with [grub-mkstandalone](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/manpages-de/grub-mkstandalone.1.de.html) also add an min set of modules need by grub for start. Don't forget to sign the "new" `grubx64.efi` with sbsign.
4. Change nvram entry with [efibootmgr](https://linux.die.net/man/8/efibootmgr) to grubx64.efi to start directly grub.
   For example:

   ```
   efibootmgr -c -b 000A -d /dev/<drive> -p 1 -L "<any name>" -l \\EFI\\ubuntu\\grubx64.efi
   ```

You can find an example here [how-to-sign-things-for-secure-boot](https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-sign-things-for-secure-boot) or [secure-boot-with-grub-and-signed-linux-and-initrd](https://ruderich.org/simon/notes/secure-boot-with-grub-and-signed-linux-and-initrd).

Do you need more information?